# Can I change the port in project clone URLs?

Tags: gitlab

I have installed gitlab in a virtual machine and set up following port forwards:

- host 8080 -> guest 80
- host 2222 -> guest 22

Now I can access gitlab web interface via `gitlab.example.com:8080` (I also have added  `gitlab.example.com` to `/etc/hosts` on the host).

However, all the project URLs for cloning look like `git@gitlab.example.com:zoran/zoran-s-project-1.git` and `http://gitlab.example.com/zoran/zoran-s-project-1.git`. Can I configure gitlab to add `2222` and `8080` ports to the clone URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can-- they're in the config/gitlab.yml file. The following two values are what you're looking for:

```
# ...
gitlab:
    # ...
    port: 8080

# ...
gitlab-shell:
    # ...
    ssh_port: 2222
```